# Pandas find an exact number of value among several

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying write a code that can read from a dataframe that has thousands of rows like:

```
name      value 
abc123     wrd
abc123     wrd
abc123     wrd
abc987     wrd
abc987     wrd
abc987     bbs
..         ..
```

I want the code to show me the name that has only the value wrd, for example in this case after the code works it should only show the result as abc123, since abc987 has both wrd and bss as value.

What I did so far is:

```
import pandas as pd

result = df[df['value'].isin(['wrd', 'bbs'])]
```

this results in both abc123 and abc987

```
result = df[df['value'].isin(['wrd'])]
```

this results in again both abc123 and abc987

What should I use instead to get name of the ones that only has the value as wrd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitler out group if not equal `wrd` with test not equal scalar by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and not matched `name`s by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
result = df[~df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['value'].ne('wrd'), 'name'])]
print (result)
     name value
0  abc123   wrd
1  abc123   wrd
2  abc123   wrd
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.loc[df['value'].ne('wrd'), 'name'])
5    abc987
Name: name, dtype: object()

print (~df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['value'].ne('wrd'), 'name']))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool()
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if match all values:

```
result = df[df['value'].eq('wrd').groupby(df['name']).transform('all')]
print (result)
     name value
0  abc123   wrd
1  abc123   wrd
2  abc123   wrd

print (df['value'].eq('wrd').groupby(df['name']).transform('all'))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks, works like a charm, when timer out will choose as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df
    name    value
0   abc123  wrd
1   abc123  wrd
2   abc123  wrd
3   abc987  wrd
4   abc987  wrd
5   abc987  bbs

df1 = df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
df1['value'] = df1['value'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == ['wrd'] else 0)

df1
    name    value
0   abc123  1
1   abc987  0

df1.loc[df1['value'].eq(1)]
    name    value
0   abc123  1
```